# Getting the Facebook Spam filter to work properly

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

At the moment the Facebook Spam filter seems for me to have a zero detection rate for real Spam messages but it does put most Messages send by people I don't know who aren't sending me Spam and who have a valid reason to message me into the "Others" folder.

Is there a way to simply deactivate the whole thing or somehow train it effectively?